# How can I implement routing analog in simple ES6 application?

Tags: javascript, html, routes, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

I want to create simple SPA application using only ES6 (without any frameworks).

But how can I implement simple routing ( like in Angular2 or another SPA framework)

`{ path: 'manage',  loadChildren: './manage/manage.module#ManageModule'   }`,

For example when my app change some route I want to call another 'component'.
And how this 'component' should like?
For example how can I add HTML file to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had try to make that really work,and it is easy.first,it has a block element in the body element:

```
<div data-role="page">some code</div>
```

then get the child component by ajax request or some method,and then insert this child component into the block element.
maybe toh